# How to pad a character with spaces when it falls between a unicode range?

Tags: python, regex, string, unicode, python-2.x

The goal is to pad a character with spaces when the `issubset` condition is met, e.g.

[in]:

```
subset = [chr(ordinal) for ordinal in range(ord(u'\u31c0'), ord(u'\u31ef'))]

text = '这是个小㇈㇋伙子'
```

[out]:

```
output_text = '这是个小 ㇈ ㇋ 伙子'
```

I could do it as such:

```
def issubset(uchar):
    if u'\u31c0' <= uchar <= u'\u31ef':
        return True
    return False

def pad_space_ifsubset(text):
    output = ""
    for ch in text:
        if issubset(ch):
            output +=  " " + ch + " "
        else:
            output += ch
    return output

text = '这是个小㇈㇋伙子'

pad_space_ifsubset(text)
```

But is there a simpler way to do this? Perhaps with regex?

Comment: What do you mean by simpler way ? more efficient, redadable ?

Comment: Either more efficient or just a different way (with regex or otherwise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) with a range pattern over the codepoints of interest, and a group backreference in the replacement string (`\g<0>` will substitute the entire substring matched, or in this case, a single character from the range):

```
import re

def pad_space_ifsubset(text):
    return re.sub(u'[\u31c0-\u31ef]', ' \g<0> ', text)
```

For example:

```
>>> text = u'这是个小㇈㇋伙子'
>>> print pad_space_ifsubset(text)
这是个小 ㇈  ㇋ 伙子
```

Comment: You do not need a capturing group around the whole pattern to replace with the whole match: `re.sub(u'[\u31c0-\u31ef]', ' \g<0> ', text)`. You do not need [`re.U`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.U) since you are not using any shorthand character classes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, you're right, and right :) I used `re.U` by habit, and overlooked the group zero. I'll update the answer, thank you.

Comment: This is definitively: the " There should be one obvious way to do it." for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Well one thing that I see is that your function `issubset`, in this case, seems useless. If don't absolutely need to create a function you could use this code instead:

```
def pad_space_ifsubset(text):
    output = ""
    for ch in text:
         if u'\u31c0' <= ch <= u'\u31ef':
            output +=  " " + ch + " "
        else:
            output += ch
     return output

text = '这是个小㇈㇋伙子'

pad_space_ifsubset(text)
```

For the space padding, you have many choices but this is the one I'd choose:

```
output += ' %s ' %ch
```

Note that what you are using is just fine in my opinion. It is a really simple case and your solution for padding spaces is readable.